# How to avoid duplicate logic?

Tags: java, code-duplication

Given two methods that are somehow duplicate logic:

```java
default void method_one(int a, int b) {
    LOGGER.info("abc");
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    doMethod_A(a, b);
    final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info(String.format("[abc] yep in %.2f sec", (end - start) / 1000f));
}

default void method_two(int c) {
    LOGGER.info("xyz");
    final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    doMethod_B(c);
    final long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info(String.format("[xyz] yep in %.2f sec", (end - start) / 1000f));
}
```

I am thinking about how to avoid duplicate logic... any ideas?

Comment: @paladin I'm curious how logic a table would help him here? Is this not just a matter of pulling out the duplicate code?

Comment: Some mod has deleted my comment -.- Logic tables always help, because with them you may find easier solutions when using boolean algebra, Karnaugh map. The problem often is, "How to articulate my problem/function as boolean expression?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
public void method_one(int a, int b) {
    doWithTimeCheck("abc", () -> doMethod_A(a, b));
}

public void method_two(int c) {
    doWithTimeCheck("xyz", () -> doMethod_B(c));
}

private static void doWithTimeCheck(String name, Runnable task) {
    LOGGER.info(name);
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    task.run();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    LOGGER.info(String.format("[%s] yep in %.2f sec", name, (end - start) / 1000.));
}

private void doMethod_A(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println("doMethod_A");
}

private void doMethod_B(int c) {
    System.out.println("doMethod_B");
}
```

Comment: Great. Perfectly solved for me THX